# is it possible to load a base64image directly into ,my canvas control without using a seperate img control

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I receive a jpeg in a byte array via web sockets.

I then convert this to base64.

I then set the source of an image control to this.

Then on the onload even of the image I assign that image to my canvas control.

Is there a way to directly load this array into  canvas control without using the image control?

my code:

```
ws.onmessage = function (frame) {
    desktopImage.src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + base64ArrayBuffer(frame);
}

desktopImage.onload = function () {
    try {
        ctxLiveViews.drawImage(desktopImage, 0, 0);
    }
    catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
}
```

ADDITIONAL:

This does not load an image to my canvas:7

```
function decodeBase64StringToArray(base64String) {
    var decodedString = window.atob(base64String);
    // either create a new array or use the .data array from your .createImageData
    var a =new  Uint8ClampedArray(decodedString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < decodedString; i++) {
        a[i] = decodedString.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return a;
}

var imgData = ctxLiveViews[3].createImageData(360, 240);
imgData.data = decodeBase64StringToArray(arrayBufferToBase64(frame));
ctxLiveViews[3].putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I dont think so. To draw image on canvas, you need image object..

Comment: (1) Decode the base64 string into an array, (2) `var imgData=createImageData...` (3) fill `imgData.data` with the contents of your decoded array, (4) `putImageData` to display the image on the canvas. BTW, I notice that you often ask for non-standard ways of achieving common tasks. Not criticizing, just want to know if you have an interesting project that imposes non-standard requirements or if you're just curious. :-)

Comment: @markE I am not sure what you mean ie decode base64 into an array. Could you post code so that I can accept pls?